# Functions' inequality solving

Tags: functions

I have a **continuous** function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for which is true:

- $f$ is **even**
- $f(x)>0\text{ }\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$
- $f$ has the **maximum value** $2=f(0)$
- $f$ is strictly increasing at $(-\infty, 0]$ and strictly decreasing at $[0,+\infty)$
- $f(-1)=1=f(1)$
- $\lim_{x\to-\infty}{f(x)}=0$
- $\lim_{x\to+\infty}{f(x)}=0$

Now I have **continuous** function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for which is true:
$$g(x)=[f(x)]^3+f(x)$$

I have already prove that:

- $g$ **has maximum** value $10=g(0)$
- the equation $g(x)+f(x)=8x$ has **exactly one positive solution**, using Bolzano's theorem, letting function $h(x)=[f(x)]^3+2f(x)-8x$ with $x\in[0,+\infty)$ ($h(0)>0$ and $h(1)<0$, so at least one solution at $(0,1)\subseteq(0,+\infty)$) and proving that $h$ is strictly decreasing at $(0,+\infty)$

Now I want to solve the inequality:
$$[f(x^4)]^3-[f(x^2)]^3<f(x^2)-f(x^4)\iff g(x^4)<g(x^2)$$
Any ideas on how can I continue my solution?

Comment: the $2$ is value of $f$ and has positive values and $f$ is **even**

Comment: for the limits yeah... my mistake, I fixed now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $h_0(u) = u^3 + u$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$ and $g(x) = h_0(f(x))$, thus$$
g(x^4) < g(x^2) \Longleftrightarrow f(x^4) < f(x^2) \Longleftrightarrow x^4 > x^2 \Longleftrightarrow x \in (-\infty, -1) \cup (1, \infty).
$$

Comment: how $h$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$, while the monotonicity of $f$ is changing at $0$?

Comment: @LeosKotrop $h_0$ (not $h$) itself has nothing to do with $f$.

Comment: But I let $h(x)=[f(x)]^3+2f(x)-8x$

Comment: But yet again the monotonicity of $f$ is changing, so how from $f(x^4)<f(x^2)$  we are going to $x^4>x^2$?

Comment: Because $f$, as you mentioned, is strictly decreasing on $[0, +\infty)$.

Comment: I want to solve the inequality at $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Is there any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x ^ 2 < 0$ or $x ^ 4 < 0$?